# Multiple index properties on a type?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to have something like this in C#? I am not very sure:

```
class Library
{
    public string Books[string title]
    {
        get{return this.GetBookByName(string title);}
    }

    public DateTime PublishingDates[string title]
    {
        get{return this.GetBookByName(string title).PublishingDate;}
    }
}
```

So it could be used as such:

```
myLibrary.Books["V For Vendetta"]
myLibrary.PublishingDates["V For Vendetta"] = ...
```

So my complete member methods that I need to implement in my framework (by calling them) are:

```
GetCustomStringValue (key)
GetCustomIntValue (key)
GetCustomBoolValue (key)
GetCustomFloatValue (key)
SetCustomStringValue (key)
SetCustomIntValue (key)
SetCustomBoolValue (key)
SetCustomFloatValue (key)
```

I want to implement them cleaner in my own type.

Comment: What is the point of this? Why can’t you just use plain old normal methods for getting and setting?

Comment: Just thought someone might be able to come up with a better solution. It doesn't seem elegant to have it this way, but just experiments.

Comment: Multiple indexed properties can be useful for WPF binding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way you could do this would be to have `Books` be a property that returns a type that has its own suitable indexer.  Here's one possible approach:

```
public class Indexer<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Func<TKey, TValue> func;

    public Indexer(Func<TKey, TValue> func)
    {
        if (func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

        this.func = func;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return func(key); }
    }
}

class Library
{
    public Indexer<string, Book> Books { get; private set; }
    public Indexer<string, DateTime> PublishingDates { get; private set; }

    public Library()
    {
        Books = new Indexer<string, Book>(GetBookByName);
        PublishingDates = new Indexer<string, DateTime>(GetPublishingDate);
    }

    private Book GetBookByName(string bookName)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private DateTime GetPublishingDate(string bookName)
    {
        return GetBookByName(bookName).PublishingDate;
    }
}
```

But you should seriously consider providing an implementation of `IDictionary<,>` instead of using this approach, as it will allow other nifty stuff, like enumeration of key-value pairs, etc.

Comment: @Joan: No problem.  Make sure you get the latest copy since I just fixed Books/PublishingDates being public fields -- now they're properties.

Comment: Thanks man, I am wondering if this would also let me to set the index values? Like myLib.Books["name"] = new Book (); etc?

Comment: @Joan Venge: If you want to do that, change the class to also take an `Action<TKey, TValue>`, store it in a field, and then add a setter: `set { action(key, value); }`. Alternatively, make the type an interface instead and get the `Library` to use a private implementation of the interface.

Comment: This solution is ridiculous. A whole separate class and a redundant delegate invocation just for the weird goal of being able to use square brackets instead of round ones. Just use normal methods, they’re just fine the way they are...

Comment: @cdhowie: Thanks for your explanation. Actually I would really appreciate if you could show me in code in your sample. Basically my get and set methods are different only.

Comment: @cdhowie: I did it based on your explanation.

Comment: @Joan: Is there a reason you can't use IDictionary?

Comment: @cdhowie: Way to go for misrepresenting what I said.

Comment: @cdhowie: You mean instead of your Indexer type?

Comment: @Joan: Yes. The indexer type is just a hack -- you should consider using a type that better represents the data.  Since Library.Books presumably represents a dictionary, using the type `IDictionary<string,Book>` for the property would probably be a good idea.  You would then set the property to something that implements that interface -- either `Dictionary<string,Book>` or a custom type.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't support it, unfortunately. It only recognises the `this[]` property, which is really just an indexable property named `Item` when compiled. The CLI supports any number of indexable properties though, and that can be reflected in some other languages like F#, where you can define your own.

Even when you do define your own in CIL or otherwise though, you still can't call them from C# like you would want to, you need to make a manual call to `get_Books(index);` for a property named `Books`. All properties are just syntactic sugar for method calls like that. C# only recognises the property named `Item` as indexable.

Comment: this is one of my arguments for why VB.NET is better than C# -- it supports parameterised (indexed) properties. (Don't worry, I have just as many reasons for why C# is better than VB.NET!)

Comment: @AAT, can you please post a link to some code samples for the vb.net? I am curious about it.

Comment: @Joan -- it's not difficult: you just define a property like "Public Property PropertyName(paramName as ParamType) as PropertyType". You can use any type or number of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, indexers have to be called `this` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664459(v=VS.71).aspx).  You can overload indexers, but remember that C# doesn't allow overloading based on return type only.  So, whereas you can have:

```
public int this[int i]
public string this[string s]
```

You couldn't have:

```
public int this[int i]
public string this[int i]
```

The .NET class library design guidelines recommend having only one indexer per class.

So in your case, there's no way to do what you're asking using indexers only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use methods?

```
class Library 
{     
    public string Books(string title)
    {         
        return this.GetBookByName(title);
    }      

    public DateTime PublishingDates(string title)
    {         
        return this.GetBookByName(title).PublishingDate;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: I could but this specific example I have has both Get and Set methods that work like this, so I thought it would be cleaner if I had one index property for each that does both, instead of 2 methods. They differ in return types and the rest is the same, you pass a key, get a value of type int, bool, float or string.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't compile, but @Kirk's point is still valid.

Comment: You need to get rid of the gets!

Comment: It compiles just fine the way it is now — and it addresses the actual problem with the question. Upvoting!

Comment: Thanks all for the edits; I hope you get my point even if the execution was lacking.  No need for OP to make things more complicated than they need to be...

Answer (score 0):

Just an exercice of style using multiple indexer parameters:

```
enum Target
{
    Books,

    PublishingDates
}

class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishingDate { get; set; }
}

class Library
{
    public object this[Target target, string title]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (target)
            {
                case Target.Books:
                    return GetBookByTitle(title);

                case Target.PublishingDates:
                    return GetBookByTitle(title).PublishingDate;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(target), 
                        target, null);
            }
        }
    }

    static Book GetBookByTitle(string title)
    {
        return new Book {Title = "V For Vendetta"};
    }
}

var book = (Book)myLibrary[Target.Books, "V For Vendetta"];
var dateTime = (DateTime)myLibrary[Target.PublishingDates, "V For Vendetta"];
```