# Exporting multiple indexed attributes from C# to tlb --> delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, com, tlb

I'm currently trying to reimplement a com interface.
This interface is currently used in a Delphi project. 
The Delphi interface code is presumably machine generated using "TLIBIMP.EXE -P")
In this autogenerated code there is for example this interface:

```
IDPets = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{679DDC30-232F-11D3-B461-00A024BEC59F}']
    function Get_Value(Index: Integer): Double; safecall;
    procedure Set_Value(Index: Integer; Value: Double); safecall;
    function Get_Pet(Index: Integer): IDPets; safecall;
    procedure Set_Pet(Index: Integer; const Ptn: IDPets); safecall; 
    property Value[Index: Integer]: Double read Get_Value write Set_Value;
    property Pet[Index: Integer]: IDPets read Get_Pet write Set_Pet;
end;
```

As you can see there are multiple property which are accessed like fields or arrays using square brackets.

What did I have achieved so far:

In C# it's possible to write one indexer accessor using this code

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("Cat")]
public ICat this[int index] { get; set; }
```

(from: [How do I export an interface written in C# to achieve Delphi code generated by TLB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099378/how-do-i-export-an-interface-written-in-c-sharp-to-achieve-delphi-code-generated))

The question:

But now I need to have more than one indexer in a class. And they only differ in their return type so I can't simply overload the "this" keyword.

So does anyone have an idea how I can implement this in C# so that I get an TLB file which than can be used to generate the Delphi code you can see in the top of this post?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Edit: I already stumbled across this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730299/3861861
It kind of work, So I'm able to export multiple properties with an index to Delphi. But the type of this properties are not the right one. For example: a double is not a double it is an IIndexerDouble (I needed to remove the generic from the indexer for the com export, so I had to write an indexer for every datatype I want to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "have more than one indexer in a class". What you really need is to have several indexed properties in Delphi.

Let's say you want to add the `Dog` indexed property. Start by adding these regular methods to the C# class:

```
public Dog GetDog(int index)
{
    ...
}

public void SetDog(int index, Dog value)
{
    ...
}
```

They will generate this:

```
function GetDog(Index: Integer): IDDogs; safecall;
procedure SetDog(Index: Integer; const Ptn: IDDogs); safecall;
```

Now just add the declaration for the indexed property:

```
property Dog[Index: Integer]: IDDogs read GetDog write SetDog;
```

Comment: That is a way which is possible to do. But that requires more manual steps to do on every iteration of the interface. I''m looking for a solution where I don't need to manipulate the .pas file after it is generated by tlbimp.exe. The original code  pas file looks like it is also completely automated generated with no manual intervention.

Comment: The original COM component was not written in C#. You could try naming the methods `get_Dog()` and `set_Dog()`, and, if you're lucky, tlibimp.exe will interpret them as an indexed property. If it doesn't, then you have no solution (other than manual editing).

Comment: This sadly doesn't work so I think there is no other solution than patching the .pas file after it is generated. I also tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23081403/3861861
But it does not work either. The first interface which the class implements get the [default] tag in the TLB file. And tlbimp.exe ignores the second interface completely.

Comment: Ok I now wrote a Patcher application. It parsed the pas File and generate properties for matching setter and getter functions and so on. Thanks for your help.